# RIGHT String function in AMPScript to add leading 0's

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

We have a system that requires users to input their ID into a field. User IDs are 6 digits long with leading 0's (when required). 
**For example: ID "789" is actually "000789"**
Unfortunately, some users are not reading the instructions to include leading 0's, and we need a system to correct the input values when needed.

Our current solution is as follows:

```
%%[
VAR @input,@LENinput,@corrected
SET @input = QUERYPARAMETER("ID")
SET @LENinput = LENGTH(@input)

IF @LENinput == 1 THEN
    SET @corrected = Concat("00000",@input)
ENDIF
IF @LENinput == 2 THEN
    SET @corrected = Concat("0000",@input)
ENDIF
IF @LENinput == 3 THEN
    SET @corrected = Concat("000",@input)
ENDIF
IF @LENinput == 4 THEN
    SET @corrected = Concat("00",@input)
ENDIF
IF @LENinput == 5 THEN
    SET @corrected = Concat("0",@input)
ENDIF
IF @LENinput == 6 THEN
    SET @corrected = @input
ENDIF

/*Do things with @corrected input value*/
]%%
```

In Excel, we would achieve this with :

```
=RIGHT("000000"&[ID], 6)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We were able to solve with the following:

```
%%[
VAR @input,@inputmod,@corrected
SET @input = QUERYPARAMETER("ID")
SET @inputmod = concat("000000",@input)
SET @corrected = Substring(@inputmod, Add(Subtract(Length(@inputmod),6),1),6)
]%%
```

The Excel equivalent is:

```
=MID(A1,(LEN(A1)-6)+1, 6)
//Assuming Cell A1 is ="000000"&[ID]
```

Trick way of doing a RIGHT() function in AMPScript!

Comment: That really is a great solution! Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

```
var @input
set @input = FormatNumber(QueryParameter("ID"), "D6")
```

Comment: Your answer is phrased as a question. As such, it might have better been posted as a comment. If you believe this is the solution to the question, I suggest you rephrase to "I recommend trying:", doing, using, changing your code, etc.